# Distribution Certificate

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning

I'm trying to make an app store build for a project that I recently inherited. After downloading and importing the distribution certificate, Xcode (naturally, since I don't have the private key) fails with "...doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private...". I suppose I can create a new distribution cert but I prefer to use the existing one. Will it be sufficient to obtain and import the private key into my keychain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes. Export it from the other machine and import it back to your keychain.

Comment: You should give the long answer, less suspense.